# REST Request response and Internal Server Error

Tags: java, http, rest

Suppose when handling a REST request, the server fails to fulfil the request and throws some Java exception, should I populate entire stack-trace in request `Response`?

What is the standard to tell user knows there is error from server side?

Comment: If code is throwing an exception, won't you be getting 500 which is an Internal Server Error by default.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj That really depends on how you set up the exception mapping, which is what this question is really about: how _should_ exceptions be mapped, and what information should be in them?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the kind of error.

If the error was caused by an error on the client side (the client didn't specify the correct parameters or something similar) send a HTTP 4XX status code (the most appropriate one)

If the error was caused by a logic error or a bug on the server side, send a HTTP 500.

For security reasons, NEVER send the stack trace to the client unless you're debugging.

Comment: The other reason for not sending the stack trace is that most clients won't know what to do with it. About the only thing they could do is send it to the service support team, but they can already read the logs…

Answer (score 1):

Return the response with a message in the body describing the error, & set the status code to 500

@morgano said it well, do check your request, because if you have properly implement your server, dealt with exception properly, the most probable source of error is the client. Many developers only perform a validation on the client, but its primordial to replicate much or all of the validation on the client on the server as well.

& of course, don't display a full stack trace, your client side system should forward your user to very nicely presented user interface with a simple 1/2 line description about the error

Answer (score 1):

The Java stacktrace is something that your service-client is (usually) not interested in, a clear error message is much more helpful in 99% of the cases.
You can add a correlation id to the returned error message and log the exception with stacktrace on the server with the correlation id.

When in doubt, ask yourself: if I called for example a github, twitter or what ever API, what would I like to get back on a failure.

They main thought behind this is that the service client can be either an internal, external, known or unknown client and that a clear error message with a way to trace the exception back to your logs is a better way to solve it and more helpful for the developers of clients.

[update]
Reading the other responses and re-reading your question, yes, include a matching HTTP result code (e.g. 500, 4xx, etc.). I thought you were already doing that.